# Facebook Graph API - Pull insights for all the posts with recent activity

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am using Facebook Graph API to pull data insights (using a read_only access token). Right now I pass the date ranges along with the PageId like -

https://graph.facebook.com/34553314232962359685674/insights/?access_token=CAADEJMW6XxsBAJB78W2fMNOLEGeHI3LxyoaFcBQjZAZBRWbdhnuJxeesnaUNj3G32Dj3rkndYn5jPKfjmJdwpYQLTaPdaeRx8ZAcfzLNcJBGLzT33IIquxYyPy49YyaktxRRlNHNotIp9tPt1KExoZAAjeF1SK5xjOejDhOKOCeCs9LFxyAuKDZANedT90bEZD&since=1388361600&until=1388448000

This returns me the insights for posts that were created in the date range but not the older posts that have had any activity (likes, shares and comments) in this time period.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please help with my question

Answer (score 0):

Vikram,

Facebook limits the data for Post Insights to 6 months or 500 posts whichever is applicable in your case.

When you query for posts for any page it will always return recent 500 posts or posts from past 6 months if they fall under the 500 criteria. (It does store data within itself but won't return it to you in API calls).